# Extract characters from string after last period

Tags: python, regex, pandas, slice

I have an `orderedDict`:

```
dict2.items():
[('A', <function __main__.percentile_50>),
 ('B', <function numpy.core.fromnumeric.sum>),
 ('C', <function numpy.core.fromnumeric.sum>),
 ('D', <function numpy.core.fromnumeric.mean>),
 etc...
```

I want to create a column that says what descriptive was used (percentile_50, sum, mean, etc.) I'm thinking of finding the last `.` and then grabbing the characters after it up until `>`. So I would end up with `percentile_50, sum, sum, mean, etc.`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you actually *tried* to do that? `rsplit` would make it pretty trivial.

Comment: @jonrsharpe No i wasn't really sure where to start. I was thinking maybe some sort of `split` or `regex`. I'll look into `rsplit`, thanks for the lead!

Comment: It looks like you're storing function objects though in your tuple rather than a str

Comment: What if someone uses just `sum` where `repr(sum)` gives `'<built-in function sum>'`, for example. Or someone has imported these functions in a qualified way such that the name doesn't contain a dot character, or changes the name at runtime?

Comment: I'm now using `str(dict2.items()[2][1]).split('function ')[1].split(' at')`. I think this should work, unless someone thinks this is a poor way of execution

Comment: If you want to get the plain function name you can use `__name__`, e.g. `numpy.core.fromnumeric.mean.__name__`.

Comment: @matt Oh that's a lot simpler, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have string in your tuples you can use `split` within a list comprehension :

```
>>> l=[('A', '<function __main__.percentile_50>'),
...  ('B', '<function numpy.core.fromnumeric.sum>'),
...  ('C', '<function numpy.core.fromnumeric.sum>'),
...  ('D', '<function numpy.core.fromnumeric.mean>')]
>>> 
>>> [(i,j.strip('>').split('.')[-1]) for i,j in l]
[('A', 'percentile_50'), ('B', 'sum'), ('C', 'sum'), ('D', 'mean')]
```

But if you have function objects you can use the [`__name__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#class.__name__) attribute for your function to extract the names :

```
>>> [(i,j.__name__) for i,j in l]
[('A', 'percentile_50'), ('B', 'sum'), ('C', 'sum'), ('D', 'mean')]
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions using regex:

```
(?<=\.)([^.>]+)(?=>$)
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hG3hL2/9)